# Sublime Text 3 + Git - Can't Push

Tags: git, sublimetext3, pantheon

Maybe I'm missing something. I have the Git package installed for ST3. Works great for almost everything - add, commit, diff, etc.. However, I can't push anything. I'm pushing to my host (Pantheon), but I get an error message every time I try. If I was doing this through terminal I would have to enter a password, but I don't get an option for a password, nor do I know where to set one up if possible.

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (password,publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Can anyone help me understand what needs to happen here or perhaps why this will not work the way I hope it will?

Comment: How do you access the remote repo? (https, ssh, ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you generated your SSH keys? Try this if you haven't yet: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: Awesome. Yes. Thank you! Exactly the push in the right direction I needed.